# Multiple dimensions conditions in SSAS MDX query not working

Tags: ssas, mdx, iif, mdx-query

I Am having the following data in my `SSAS` cube.

[image]

> My need is to get the value of the measure based on two conditions with two different dimensions using the `MDX`.

> In this example data, I need to get the `Reseller Sales Amount` value where the value of `Title` dimension is equal to **Sales Representative** and the value of the `Gender`dimension is equal to **Male** condition.

I have tried to achieve the requirement with the [Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/case-statement-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) statement and [IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/iif-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) function available in the `MDX` but it is not working.

Please find the queries I have tried with different functions.

**Using Case statement:**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS
CASE WHEN [Employee].[Title].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "Sales Representative" THEN (CASE
WHEN [Employee].[Gender].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "Male"
THEN [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ELSE 0 END)ELSE 0 END select [Measures].[Expression1] on Columns from [Sales Targets]
```

**Using IIF() function:**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS
IIF( [Employee].[Title].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "Sales Representative" AND [Employee].[Gender].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = "Male",
[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount], 0)
SELECT{
[Measures].[Expression1]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Sales Targets] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

The result that I am getting for both queries is 0.

[image]

> Can anyone please guide me to get the proper result using `MDX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/tuples?view=asallproducts-allversions) either directly in the calculated measure:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS
([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount], [Employee].[Title].[Sales Representative], [Employee].[Gender].[Male])
select [Measures].[Expression1] on Columns 
from [Sales Targets]
```

Or you can put a Tuple in the where clause if you want it to apply to all cells in the query:

```
Select [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] on Columns 
from [Sales Targets]
where ([Employee].[Title].[Sales Representative], [Employee].[Gender].[Male])
```

Comment: Additionally I need to get the measure value based on 3 conditions and there is 2 conditions from same dimension and another 1 is from different dimension.

i.e., From the above example data, I need to get the Reseller Sales Amount value where the value of Title dimension is equal to Sales Representative & Pacific Sales Manager and the value of the Gender dimension is equal to Male condition.

My expected output is 43152691.31

Can you please assist on this?